What happens when you create an instance of a class but don't assign it to a variable
I'm learning C++ and encountered something that I don't fully understand. If I have a class definition with member variables and methods, I would normally instantiate that class by either assigning it a variable name or including it in a set, map, etc. so that I can reference each instance when needed.
class Person {
    private:
        string name;
        int age;
    public:
        Person() : name(""), age(0) {}
        Person(string name, int age) : 
            name(name), age(age) {
            }
        void print() const {
            cout << name << ": " << age << flush;
        }
    };

This is my class definition. To create an instance and use a method I would do the following.
int main() {
    Person demo = Person("Felix",28);
    demo.print();
    return 0;
}
returns: Felix: 28

But I can also declare it in place like so.
int main() {
    Person("Felix",28);
    return 0;
}

My question is what is the purpose of declaring classes with no way of referencing them? Am I mistaken in my understanding of how to declare and use instances of a class?

you're not declaring a class there, you are creating an anonymous object. It's not very useful by itself unless the constructor has specific side effects you wanted to invoke. But you could call Person("Felix", 28).print() if you wanted

Echoing @Botje's comment, consider moving your print method into the constructor. Now your anonymous object executes a side effect that you invoke, namely streaming the name and age to stdout.

This is not limited to classes, you can also write 5;, which is also pretty useless.

Syntax rules of all useful languages let to express limitless nonsense in those languages.

@bop except that there can be side effects in the ctor and the dtor.

So when Person("Felix",28); is written in place, does it create an instance of the class and immediately discard it, or is there an instance floating in memory somewhere with no way to use it? I'm trying to understand a use case for an anonymous object.

@Jujimufoo there is no direct use case for your example. It's just sometimes you don't really need a named instance. Something like return Application{args, argv}.run();

The program will make room on the stack, call the constructor, and call the destructor. Nothing "floating in memory somewhere".

@BoP your example is actually quite useful with fold expressions.

Often there is no purpose -- for some classes it's an error -- which leads to questions like How to ensure that an object is assigned to a variable, How do you give the rvalue generated by a constructor the lifetime of an lvalue?, Preventing users from creating unnamed instances of a class, and How to avoid C++ anonymous objects.
